# What makes something a (population) moment condition?

Tags: statistics

In my studies I have learned that moments are the mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis etc defined as $ \mathbb{E}(X), \mathbb{E}(X^2), \mathbb{E}(X^3) $ etc.

I also understood that, in this case, moment conditions look like $\mathbb{E}(X - \mu) = 0 $ and $ \mathbb{E}(X^2 - \sigma^2) = 0$.

However, now we are covering the MM and GMM estimators for my masters econometrics and all of a sudden moment conditions look way different. I will take the linear regression $ y_i = a + bx_i +e_i$ (normally distributed errors with var = $\sigma^2$) as an example where the teacher formulated the following moments: $$ \mathbb{E}[e_i] =0 \\ \mathbb{E}[e_ix_i] = 0 \\ \mathbb{E}[e_i^2] = \sigma^2$$

I have been searching alot for an explanation online why the above can be considered moments and how I to know the logic behind the concept so I can find them myself. However, everywhere I look I just get the regular expressions for mean, variance etc whicg I started the post with. Furthermore, if I look further in more advanced literature it is taken for granted that you know what these moments and moment conditions are. I am hoping if anyone can explain this to me or share a source which will help me understand.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[e_i] =0$ and $\mathbb{E}[e_i^2] = \sigma^2$ are clearly moment conditions on $e_i$, while $\mathbb{E}[e_ix_i] = 0$ is related to covariance between $e_i$ and $x_i$

Comment: apart for the mean and variance, with the last one you are saying that the error and your rv are uncorrelated